# Запись в переменную перед выполнением кода

Tags: c++

Делаю приложение авторизации посредством tcp. Вот код клиента:

```
char msg1[256];
//char login, password;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

//тут было считывание, но считывание пароля программа не дожидалась, а сразу коннектилась к серверу. 
                //std::cout << "login: ";
        //std::cin >> login;
        //std::cout << "password: ";
        //std::cin >> password;

    WSADATA wsaData;
    WORD DLLVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
    if (WSAStartup(DLLVersion, &wsaData) != 0) {
        std::cout << "Critical Error" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    int sizeofaddr = sizeof(addr);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    addr.sin_port = htons(1111);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    SOCKET Connection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
    if (connect(Connection, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0) {
    std::cout << "Error Connecting\n";
    return 1;
}
    std::cout << "Connected\n";
    char  msg[256];
    recv(Connection, msg, sizeof(msg), NULL);
    std::cout << msg << std::endl;


// Хочу передать пару логин и пароль одним пакетом (через пробел)
    while (true) {
        send(Connection, msg1, sizeof(msg1), NULL);
        Sleep(10);
    }


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Вообщем как записать и логин и пароль в msg1, а потом отправить?

Comment: Сделайте через с++ строки и не парьтесь. `std::string login, password; std::string msg1 = login + " " + password; send(Connection, msg1.c_str(), msg.size(), NULL);` Если очень нужно чисто си, то вам поможет `strcat`. http://cppstudio.com/post/695/ И длину си строки стоит считать через strlen, чтобы мусор не отправлять.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Это работает

Comment: @ДмитрийЗиненко оформите свой комментарий как ответ, чтобы будущие пользователи его не пропустили